# Python: sending syslog message with priority value with RFC 3164

Tags: python, logging, syslog, python-logging

please help to how to use encodePriority(facility, priority) class of logging module in python.
Below sample python code is sending messages to syslog server and, remote UNIX expects the log in RFC3164, i am trying ways to set priority value as prefix for each syslog message, which is calculated by  multiplying the Facility number by 8 and then adding the numerical value of the Severity.

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ipaddress = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(localhost)s  %(message)s', datefmt='%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S');
loggerConf = setup_logger(name="mylogger3", logfile='logs/my.log', formatter=log_format, level=10, disableStderrLogger=True)
logger2 = logging.LoggerAdapter(loggerConf, {'localhost': ipaddress})
logger2.info("sample message")



expected output:

<24>Apr 25 2020 02:38:24  10.20.30.40  sample message
```

where 24 is calculated from facility*8 + Severity ==>assuming i set fac to 3, severity to 0..

as per RFC 3164:

```
   Numerical             Facility
      Code

       0             kernel messages
       1             user-level messages
       2             mail system
       3             system daemons
       4             security/authorization messages (note 1)
       5             messages generated internally by syslogd
       6             line printer subsystem
       7             network news subsystem
       8             UUCP subsystem
       9             clock daemon (note 2)
      10             security/authorization messages (note 1)
      11             FTP daemon
      12             NTP subsystem
      13             log audit (note 1)
      14             log alert (note 1)
      15             clock daemon (note 2)
      16             local use 0  (local0)
      17             local use 1  (local1)
      18             local use 2  (local2)
      19             local use 3  (local3)
      20             local use 4  (local4)
      21             local use 5  (local5)
      22             local use 6  (local6)
      23             local use 7  (local7)

    Numerical         Severity
      Code

       0       Emergency: system is unusable
       1       Alert: action must be taken immediately
       2       Critical: critical conditions
       3       Error: error conditions
       4       Warning: warning conditions
       5       Notice: normal but significant condition
       6       Informational: informational messages
       7       Debug: debug-level messages
```